# How to override exposed filters view

Tags: 7, forms, views

I have one form of exposed filters of view. I need to override few elements of that, like change options for select box dropdown and like that.

For that I have created view, and used `hook_form_alter`, but the changes are not reflecting.

My work:

```
function custom_module_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 
         'views-exposed-form-advanced-search-page') {

         print_r($form['submit']);  //debug
         $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Search');
         print_r($form['submit']); //debug
    }
}
```

As shown above, to test, I am just trying to alter the label of submit button, and for debugging, I have added two `print_f`, statement, output of which are as follows:

First print_f():

```
Array ( [#name] => 
        [#type] => submit 
        [#value] => Apply 
        [#id] => edit-submit-advanced-search 
      )
```

Second print_f():

```
Array ( [#name] => 
        [#type] => submit 
        [#value] => Search
        [#id] => edit-submit-advanced-search 
     )
```

As shown, the label is changing, but it is not reflecting to the form.

Considering module weight, I have also tried giving more weight to my module tham views weight. But nothing changed.

Please suggest, if I am missing something.

-- Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the variable as reference.

So the function would should be

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```